# Node js express routing not working, not showing any errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, url-routing

So I'm trying to make a dynamic route, and the route keeps throwing a error can not get, I've tried just making it a normal route and no matter what I'm doing I cant get this route to work, and the console isnt throwing any errors. If someone is seeing something I'm missing I'd appreciate the help. Thanks

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const pug = require("pug");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");
const viewRoutes = require("./router/viewRoutes");

const app = express();

app.set("view engine", "pug");
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/public`));

app.use(express.json({ limit: "10kb" }));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/", viewRoutes);
// app.get("/symbol", viewRoutes);

module.exports = app;
```

viewRoutes.js

```
const express = require("express");
const viewController = require("../controllers/viewController");

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", viewController.homePage);
router.get("/:symbol", viewController.symbolDetails);

module.exports = router;
```

controller.js

```
exports.symbolDetails = async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.params.symbol);
  res.status(200).end("Hello world");
};
```

Comment: Just a typo. Use `app.use("/", viewRoutes)` (not `app.get()`). See https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router

Comment: Jesus I cant believe I overlooked that. Thank you